# Batch changing titles of mkv files in multiple directories

Tags: windows, batch-file, mkv

Ok, I'm total new at this...
Basically I'm using a tool call mkvpropedit to edit the title of my .mkv files
My aim is to create a batch the goes through all sub directories and replace the mkv file titles with their file name.

I have made the following progress...

```
for %%A in (*.mkv) do "C:\mkvpropedit.exe" "%%A" --edit info --set title="%%A"
```

Issue with [1]: It works fine but does not affect all sub directories and I would have to use the batch in all the sub directories one by one which will be time consuming.

```
for /R "C:\whatever" %%I in (*mkv) do "C:\whatever\mkvpropedit.exe" "%%I" --edit info --set title="%%I"
```

Issue here, It affects all sub directories but my .mkv file titles end up with the entire directory pathway instead of the file name.

Could anyone help me here? Thanks a lot in advance.

BTW if anyone know how to set a long directory pathway into a short form to be use repeated throughout the script (eg. "C:\whatever\whatever...\mkvpropeditexe into mkvpropedit", that would be helpful.

Comment: in second script. change `%%I` to `%%~nxI%`

Comment: The __FOR__ command to process all *.mkv files of a directory and all its subdirectories is: `for /F "delims=" %%I in ('dir /A-D-H /B /S "Base Folder Path\*.mkv" 2^>nul') do`. I recommend to run this command first from command line as `for /F "delims=" %I in ('dir /A-D-H /B /S "Base Folder Path\*.mkv" 2^>nul') do @echo %I` to see what it finds. Run in command prompt window `for /?` and `dir /?` for help on the two used commands.

Comment: All this information you have been given is clearly provided in the help files of the commands you are using. Please consider reading the help files first before asking questions.

Comment: Just correction on my comment, I made a typo. it should not contain the last `%` it should be  `%%~nxI`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you use `%%~nI` or `%%~nxI` (as suggested by Gerhard Barnard) depends on how you want the title: "**n**ame" only or "**n**ame.e**x**tension".

for `how to set a long directory pathway into a short form to be use repeated throughout the script`; set a variable with the full path\name and use the variable:

```
set "mkv=C:\whatever\mkvpropedit.exe"
for /R "C:\whatever" %%I in (*.mkv) do "%mkv%" "%%I" --edit info --set title="%%~nI"
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the help from this thread, here's a little more elaborate batch script I developed:

```
rem This Bat file will take MKV filenames and apply them to MKV info titles

@echo off

rem Modify next line to path where mkvpropedit.exe  !!!!!!!!!

cd "C:\Program Files\MKVToolNix"

set /A errors1=0

rem Modify next line to path where MKV files are. This will also modify MKV's in subdirectories. !!!!!!!!!

for /R "X:\Move" %%X in (*.mkv) DO CALL :loopbody %%X

echo.
echo.
echo Total Errors = %errors1%
echo.
pause

GOTO :EOF


:loopbody

set title0=%*

set "title1=%title0:.mkv=%"

set "title2=%title1:\=" & set "title2=%"

rem The following two lines are to remove additional info I use in the filenames.

set "title3=%title2: 1080p=%"

set "title4=%title3: 720p=%"

set command1=mkvpropedit "%title0%" --edit info --set "title=%title4%"

for /f "delims=" %%a in ('%command1%') do @set response1=%%a

echo %title2%

echo %response1%

echo.

echo.

if /i "%response1:~0,5%"=="Error" (set /A errors1=%errors1% + 1)

GOTO :EOF
```